# How to turn the camera light (torch) off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media, quaggajs

I'm creating an app to read barcodes. I'm using QuaggaJS as a barcode reader library. My problem is that I can turn the torch on, but I can't turn it off.

```
var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{torch:true}]}); //Torch is on
track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{torch:false}]}); //Torch still on :(
```

Is there a way to turn the torch off?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: The stream restart is only the trick that helped me to overcome this issue (android 8 xiaomi)

Answer (score 0):

you are using two separate `applyConstraints` calls without waiting for the first one to complete. The applyConstraints method is asynchronous, and the second call is getting executed before the first one finishes. To fix this, you can using the `then` method

```
var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();

track.applyConstraints({
        advanced: [{
            torch: true
        }]
    })
    .then(function() {
        // Torch is on
        console.log('Torch turned on successfully');

        // Now, turn off the torch
        return track.applyConstraints({
            advanced: [{
                torch: false
            }]
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        // Torch is off
        console.log('Torch turned off successfully');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error applying constraints:', error);
    });
```